# Raspberry [Errno 13] permission denied opening file txt

Tags: admin, raspberry-pi3

I am using a raspberry pi 3 with Jessie. 
In my code, I need to read a file.txt in a loop but i got the error N13 saying Permission denied: 'file.txt'. 
I am running the code using thonny. 
Any solution ?

i solved from cmd window tiping sudo python3 filename.py

but i need to do it everytime i want to launch the code, there is a way to make it definitive?

Comment: Have you checked the file permissions?

Comment: Check your file permissions, and the user that is running the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check FILE PERMISSIONS. 
Do it from root.
Whenever there is permission denied error appears/occurs, its either file permissions in case of files or  wrong password entered.